# Missing message for key "registration.jsp.title" in bundle "(default bundle)" for locale en_GB

Tags: java, web-applications, struts

I'm completely new to `Struts 1.3.10` and I'm trying to implement a simple registration application but every time I try to run the damned thing, I get the following message:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Missing message for key "registration.jsp.title" in bundle "(default bundle)" for locale en_GB
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:491)
```

My `registration.jsp` file includes the following tag library references:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-logic" prefix="logic" %>

<html:html>

<head>
    <title><bean:message key="registration.jsp.title"/></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .error { color: red; font-weight:bold }
    </style>
</head>
```

And I believe that the tag libraries are being found correctly through the URI references in `web.xml` such as follows:

```
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-bean</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
```

So I'm assuming that the problem is to do with the location of the my `Application.properties` file containing the messages.

Can anyone tell me where this should be located? Currently it is in a folder called resources which, like `WEB-INF`, is a sub folder of `Web pages`.

I'm using NetBeans 7.2 and have imported the `Struts 1.3.10` framework into my project and am using Tomcat 6.X.

Comment: yes, find the localization properties file and add `registration.jsp.title` value

Comment: File Application.properties currently contains a message with this key.

Comment: add to your config resources: `<message-resources parameter="example.ApplicationResources"/>` with correct path in parameter attribute

Comment: Should that be something like: `<message-resources parameter="\resources\Application.properties"/>` where in my case `resources` is a sub folder of Web Pages

Comment: this article could help you http://www.allapplabs.com/struts/struts_internationalization.htm